# Apache can't rewrite "&" as part of TAG in URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ /test.php?TAG=$1 [L]
```

With

```
/tag/m%26m
```

I would expect **m&m** at server side. ( **&** was URL encoded into %26)

For some reason the rewrite engine treat it as

```
/test.php?TAG=m&m
```

As if the it was accessed with

```
/tag/m&m
```

The var_dump($_GET) gives

```
array(2) {
    ["TAG"]=>  string(1) "m"
    ["m"]=>  string(0) ""
}
```

But if I access

```
/test.php?TAG=m%26m
```

It works fine, and the var_dump($_GET) gives

```
array(1) {
    ["TAG"]=> string(3) "m&m"
}
```

So the problem must have something to do with the Apache rewrite engine. If it is not a bug, what is the right way to configure the rewrite rule for it to work?

**More**
I enabled the rewrite log and found:

```
applying pattern '^tag/([^/]+)/?$' to uri 'tag/m&m'
```

So it looks like the URL encoded **%26** was decoded back to **&**. The apache version is 2.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [B (escape backreferences) flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ /test.php?TAG=$1 [L,B]
```

Not to be confused with the NE (no escape) flag which prevents special characters such as & and ? and # from being urlencoded in the rewritten URL.  You can read more about these and other [mod_rewrite flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked the documentation, realized the B flag is the solution to prevent **m%26m** from being **unescaped** to **m&m**. NE flag works for the destination URL and B works for the source URL